# Number of different strings I can get using PHP random string shuffle

Tags: php, math, random, permutation

I currently run a URL shortening website called http://nn.pe and use a 6 char random hash with this code,

```
$charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    return substr(str_shuffle($charset), 0, 6);
```

I was wondering how many different strings are there using those characters and integers?

You don't need to be exact, just within a million I guess.

Comment: Don't use `str_shuffle` if you want it to be unique. It uses the built-in random number generator, which on some platforms only generates just over 32000 different values.

Comment: Well this function will run over and over if the hash it generates is already in use.

Comment: @HarryBeasant You'd have a massive infinite loop if the RNG is having problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Warning

I just looked it up in the PHP 5.3.8 source. `php_rand()` is used. This is the C equivalent of `rand()`. I'd be very careful with `str_shuffle`!! It will (usually) give you as many possibilities as `getrandmax()` outputs, which can be 32,768 on Windows.

On most systems you'll have a theoretical maximum of 2.1 billion though.

Comment: I think you can assume a Fisher Yates

Comment: @ThomasAhle I'm not sure how that's relevant. If the RNG keeps returning the same numbers for one seed (32bit RNG, for example), the maximum randomness of the shuffling is based on the limit of the RNG.

Comment: I don't see why the number of bits in the generator is relevant.

Comment: @ThomasAhle Then you don't know how a shuffling algorithm works. A shuffling algorithm based on a RNG cannot have more outcomes than the RNG has seeds.

Comment: Good point, but you'll almost always see that those two are equal. (You are very much correct though)

Comment: @Phoenix Tom is still right that you can't generate more unique sequences than the number of seeds.

Comment: You never want to return as many bits from your generator as it uses as seed/state. If you did that an attacker could figure out the seed easily.

Comment: @ThomasAhle `rand()` and `mt_rand()` aren't designed to handle cryptographic stuff. They simply return a somewhat random number.

Answer (score 3):

`62^6 = 56,800,235,584`

There's 62 combinations within [a-zA-Z0-9] amongst a 6 character hash.

Answer (score 3):

If the shuffle is a proper shuffle like Fisher Yates, you have (26*2+10)!/(26*2+10-6)! = 62!/56! = 44,261,653,680 Possibilities, because we don't have replacement.

Comment: Notice that it has to be a "proper" shuffle for my answer to matter. That is it must generate all permutations (with equal probability). See Toms answer why that is probably not the case for the php shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

Fifty-six billion, eight hundred million.

For each of the given positions in the hash you have 26 + 26 + 10 options. This gives you 62^6 possible strings. 62^6 = 56 800 235 584.

Comment: `n^r` is only accurate if repetition is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`62^6 = 56,800,235,584` combinations.

However, you must have control for collisions.

Comment: Yes i have that in place, if it generates on already used, it will simple run the function again.